# Unknown class? C2143 syntax error: missing ";" before '*'

Tags: c++, syntax, syntax-error, rhapsody

I get the error "C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' in Track.h
I believe this is due to a "missing" class definition.

These are the 3 header files:

Topics.h, the package-level header file, which #includes everything else:

```
#ifndef Topics_H
#define Topics_H

#include <oxf\oxf.h>
#include "Request.h"
#include "TDPoint.h"
#include "Track.h"
#include "TrackReport.h"

#endif
```

Then there's TDPoint (as in "3DPoint"), which simply defines a class with 3 long attributes:

```
#ifndef TDPoint_H
#define TDPoint_H

#include <oxf\oxf.h> // Just IBM Rational Rhapsody's Framework
#include "Topics.h"

class TDPoint {
    ////    Constructors and destructors    ////

public :

    TDPoint();

    ~TDPoint();

    ////    Additional operations    ////

long getX() const;    
void setX(long p_x);
long getY() const;    
void setY(long p_y);    
long getZ() const;
void setZ(long p_z);

    ////    Attributes    ////

protected :

    long x;    
    long y;    
    long z;};

#endif
```

But the problem lies here, in the marked line:

```
#ifndef Track_H
#define Track_H

#include <oxf\oxf.h> // Just IBM Rational Rhapsody's Framework
#include "Topics.h"
#include "TDPoint.h"

class Track {

public :

    ////    Operations     ////

    std::string getId() const;

    void setId(std::string p_id);

    TDPoint* getPosition() const; // <--- This line, the first line to use TDPoint, throws the error

    ////    Attributes    ////

protected :

    std::string id;   

    TDPoint position;

public :

     Track();
     ~Track();
};

#endif
```

My guess was that the compiler (MS VS2008/ MSVC9) simply didn't know the class "TDPoint." But even defining the class in the same header file as "Track", or using a forward declaration like "class TDPoint" (which then throws the error: undefined class) didn't help.
The code was auto-generated from Rhapsody, if that makes any difference.

But maybe the error is something else entirely?

Comment: You have `void setId(std::string p_id);`, yet I don't see an include for `<string>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Topics.h` includes `TDPoint.h` and `Track.h`

`TDPoint.h` includes `Topics.h`

and `Track.h` includes both `Topics.h` and `TDPoint.h`

This feels like a circular include... You should either forward declare your classes to solve it or modify `Topics.h` to not to have circularity.

Comment: Thanks, i had a suspicion that it was something as obvious as that. I thought the include guards would resolve this. Now i learned the difference between multiple and circular includes - and that include guards don't protect against the latter.
Still sad to see auto-generated code from Rhapsody that makes a simple mistake as this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have circular inclusion: The file `Track.h` includes `Topics.h` which includes `TDPoints.h` which includes `Topics.h` which includes `Track.h` where the `TDPoint` class is not declared.

In fact, the `TDPoint.h` doesn't need any header files at all, it's completely independant (as per the code shown in your question).

The `Track.h` file only needs to include `TDPoint.h`, not `Topics.h`. (And possibly `<string>`.)

General hint: Include as few headers as possible in a header file.

Comment: Thanks, sadly i can only choose 1 answer - yours being identical, i chose the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but I would like to add few things for completeness.

**1. Cause:** your project have circular including, specifically, when you compile "TDPoint.cpp", the compiler will do the following

```
#include "TDPoint.h" //start compiling TDPoint.h
#include "Topics.h" //start compiling Topics.h
#include "TDPoint.h" //compilation of TDPoint.h skipped because it's guarded
#include "Track.h" //start compiling Track.h
#include "Topics.h" //compilation of Topics.h skipped because it's guarded
 //resume compiling Track.h 
... 
TDPoint* getPosition() const; //=> error TDPoint is not defined

=>C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
```

**2. Counter measure:** replace including in header by forward declaration to remove circle of including, and use including in .cpp files. Specifically, forward declaration means: 
(in Topics.h)

```
#ifndef Topics_H
#define Topics_H
#include <oxf\oxf.h>
#include "Request.h"
class TDPoint;  //Forward declaration to replace #include "TDPoint.h"
class Track; //Forward declaration to replace #include "Track.h"
#include "TrackReport.h"
#endif
```